# Angular Material RC5 Select blanks out bottom 20% of window

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the most recent version of Angular Material.  I have a select box populated by an array.  When I click on the Select Box, the options get properly populated but the screen goes blank after the very top item in the box.  If I use my arrow keys the select options works and when I release, the Select Option gets populated with the proper select item and the screen returns to normal.  I cannot see the option I am choosing because the screen is white across that area and the entire screen is white for the bottom 20% or so.  Here is my code:

```
<div style="line-height: 24px; margin: 8px;"  flex="50">
    <label>Case Mgr.</label>       
      <md-select ng-model="zbcase.assistant">
          <md-optgroup label="assts">
              <md-option ng-value="asst" ng-repeat="asst in assts">{{asst}}    
              </md-option>
          </md-optgroup>
      </md-select>
</div>
```

Yet if I go to the Angular Material Webpage and try their demo, no issues.  It works fine.

Any thoughts?  Thank you

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/AXNBjj

Comment: Still having the issue.  It appears to be setting my CSS Body style to have a top value of -184 or some such negative number.  The problem must be upstream somewhere.  Any other ideas???